# I want to end my tag when a particular child tag comes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

So my xml contents as follows:

Original XML:

```
 <p id="ACB1234" trackparabreak="true">
   <t>
     <apple>Some texts</apple>          
        <p trackparabreak="true">
            <t> Some texts </t>
        </p>
     <orange>Some Texts</orange>
   </t>
 </p>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <p id="ACB1234" trackparabreak="true">
      <t>
        <apple>Some texts</apple>
      </t>
   </p>
   <p trackparabreak="true">
      <t>  Some texts </t>
   </p>
   <p>
      <t>
        <orange> Some Texts </orange>
      <t>
   <p>
```

How can we get the desired output using xslt-1.0 ?

Comment: Can you give us some more details, what are the rules? Why does <apple> stay within the first p/t and the rest is moved? The given example/output is not enough to write a proper XSLT to cover possible cases.

Comment: Your "Desired Output"is not well-formed XML; there can be only one root element.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment below your question, there isn't enough information to cover all cases, but by tweaking below's XSLT you can probably achieve what you need. warning: hackery! todo: deal with attributes and normalize space.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(ancestor::p)]">
    <p>
        <t>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="t/apple"/>
        </t>
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="t/*[not(self::apple)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apple">
    <apple>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </apple>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[ancestor::p]">
    <p>
        <t>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </t>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orange">
    <p>
        <t>
            <orange>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </orange>
        </t>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<p id="ACB1234" trackparabreak="true">
  <t>
    <apple>APPLE TEXT</apple>          
    <p trackparabreak="true">
        <t>PARA INSIDE TEXT</t>
    </p>
    <orange>ORANGE TEXT</orange>
  </t>
</p>
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <p>
    <t>
        <apple>APPLE TEXT</apple>
    </t>
  </p>
  <p>
    <t> PARA INSIDE TEXT </t>
  </p>
  <p>
    <t>
        <orange>ORANGE TEXT</orange>
    </t>
  </p>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't create tags in a serial output file, it creates nodes in a tree. Creating an element node is an indivisible operation, you can't create the "start of the node" and the "end of the node" as independent actions at different times. So you've got the wrong model in your head as to how the processing works, and that's going to make it difficult to solve the problem.

Whereas @Marcin has guessed that the problem is about apples and oranges, my guess is that it's about trackparabreak attributes. Perhaps (s)he's right and I'm wrong, but you've explained it so badly that we can only guess.

It's a tough problem and I'm not going to invest the time in a complete solution, partly because things like this are so much easier in XSLT 2.0 and I hate working with one hand tied behind my back, and partly because there's no point writing lots of code when the requirements aren't clear. For example, I've no idea what you want to do with a `<p>` that doesn't have the trackparabreak attribute, because there isn't one in your example.

The usual technique for this kind of problem is sibling recursion. The model here is that in the template rule for a parent element, you apply-templates to the first child (`child::*[1]`), and in the template rule for a child element, after processing the children, you apply-templates to the next sibling (`following-sibling::*[1]`); except when you hit a break condition like the presence of trackparabreak, in which case you stop the sibling recursion and unwind the stack.